# Why is the boolean value in FormRecord possibly undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to make an assignment in the handler method but the type of `this.form.value` is `Partial<{ [key: string]: boolean }>` and the compiler is telling me that the `string` index signatures are incompatible and that undefined is not assignable to `boolean`.

I don't understand how the boolean is considered to be possibly undefined when the control is explicitly created with an initial value that is not null or undefined.

How can I handle this typing without having to use the null forgiving operator? (`!`)

```
export interface TableColumn {
  visible?: boolean;
  key: string;
}

...

@Input() public columns: TableColumn[] = [];

public form: FormRecord<FormControl<boolean>>;

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this._fb.nonNullable.record({});
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.columns.forEach((col: TableColumn) => {
    const control = this._fb.nonNullable.control<boolean>(col.visible ?? true);
    this.form.addControl(col.key, control);
  })
}

public handler(): void {
  const val: Record<string, boolean> = this.form.value;
  const value: { [key: string]: boolean } = this.form.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it the type it is telling you to:

```js
const val: Partial<{[x: string]: boolean}> = this.form.value;
```

or just don't assign a type and let typescript *infer* it.

```js
const val = this.form.value; // type is Partial<{[x: string]: boolean}>
```

The reason that the boolean can be undefined is that you can index a string that is not a key.

Example:

```js
this.form.value["someRandomString"] // undefined
```

This is the advantage of using `Partial`, it forces you to check this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.form.value` is `Partial<{ [x: string]: boolean }>`, so you could use type assertion:

```
const val: Record<string, boolean> = this.form.value as Record<string, boolean>;
const value: { [key: string]: boolean } = this.form.value as Record<string, boolean>;
```

Or, just make the compiler happy and say the booleans could be undefined:

```
const val: Record<string, boolean | undefined> = this.form.value;
const value: { [key: string]: boolean | undefined } = this.form.value;
```